# Communicate from a c++ program to a running R process

Tags: c++, r

I have a problem communicating between 2 running processes. I have an R program which runs first, completes running half the script and then waits for the signal that a C++ program has completed running at around a specific time.

The layman's approach I could think of was to
(1) Make the R program poll/sleep and wake up every 10 milliseconds if possible and check some file contents which would indicate the c++ program completed. The c++ program would append the right signal to the file in question.

I am looking for a more performance efficient solution.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

You can have the R script save its output to disk, then exit. The C++ program can then start R when it completes, read the output, and continue where the first script left off.

Comment: May be I should add more detail to be precise, I am looking for performance better than executing a system command from either c++ or R to execute the other program. Would like to communicate something like over a pipe/socket or even better if possible.